# getting "_throw_bad_array_new_lengthv" when trying to use std::vector::push_back inside a class

Tags: c++, runtime-error, stdvector

I'm creating a custom language parser in C++, I'm struggling with a runtime error, where I have a `std::vector<std::string>` member of a class with a constructor.
The full error is:

```
The procedure entry point
_ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv could no be located
in the dynamic link library
"path_to_executable"
```

This error is throw whenever I try to use std::vector::push_back in my code, but shouldn't std::vector be a dynamically sized data container? Why is this error occurring?

Some of my codes:

```cpp
//"lib/cursor.h"

#ifndef T_CURSOR
#define T_CURSOR

#include <iostream>

struct Cursor
{
private:
    std::string input;
    int inputLength;

    char getChar(int p);

public:
    char character;
    int pos;
    int line;
    int column;
    bool eof;
    bool lineBreak;

    Cursor(std::string i);

    void walk(bool back = false);
    void walkTimes(int times, bool back = false);
    void move(int toPos);
    void skipIgnore();
    std::string toString();
};

#endif
```

```cpp
//"lib/cursor.cpp"

#include <sstream>
#include "cursor.h"

Cursor::Cursor(std::string i)
{
    this->input = i;
    this->inputLength = i.length();
    this->character = i.at(0);
    this->pos = 0;
    this->line = 0;
    this->column = 0;
    this->eof = false;
    this->lineBreak = false;
}

char Cursor::getChar(int pos)
{
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= this->inputLength)
    {
        return EOF;
    }
    return this->input.at(pos);
}

void Cursor::walk(bool back)
{
    if (back)
    {
        this->pos--;
        this->column--;
        if (this->lineBreak)
        {
            this->line--;
            this->column = 0;
            for (int i = this->pos - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (this->getChar(i) == '\n')
                    break;
                this->column++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this->pos++;
        this->column++;
        if (this->lineBreak)
        {
            this->line++;
            this->column = 0;
        }
    }
    this->character = this->getChar(this->pos);
    this->eof = this->character == EOF;
    this->lineBreak = this->character == '\n';
}

void Cursor::walkTimes(int times, bool back)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        this->walk(back);
    }
}

void Cursor::move(int pos)
{
    if (pos < 0)
        pos = 0;
    if (pos > this->inputLength - 1)
        pos = this->inputLength - 1;

    this->pos = 0;
    this->character = this->input.at(0);
    this->line = 0;
    this->column = 0;
    this->eof = false;
    this->lineBreak = this->character == '\n';

    while (this->pos < pos)
        this->walk();
}

void Cursor::skipIgnore()
{
    while (this->character == ' ' ||
                 this->character == '\n' ||
                 this->character == '\t')
        this->walk();

    if (this->character == '#')
    {
        while (!this->eof && this->character != '\n')
            this->walk();
    }

    while (this->character == ' ' ||
                 this->character == '\n' ||
                 this->character == '\t')
        this->walk();
}

std::string Cursor::toString()
{
    std::stringstream ss("");
    ss << "(P:" << this->pos;
    ss << " L:" << this->line;
    ss << " C:" << this->column;
    ss << " \"" << this->character << "\")";

    return ss.str();
}
```

```cpp
//"lib/lexer.h"
#ifndef T_LEXER
#define T_LEXER

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "cursor.h"

class Lexer
{
private:
    std::string input;

protected:
    Cursor cursor;
    std::vector<std::string> matchStack;
    std::vector<std::vector<Cursor>> cursorStack;

public:
    Lexer(std::string input);

    std::string getStr(int pos);
    void setStr(int pos, std::string str);
    Cursor getCursorStart(int pos);
    Cursor getCursorEnd(int pos);

    bool match(std::string str);
};

#endif
```

```cpp
//"lib/lexer.cpp"
#include "lexer.h"

Lexer::Lexer(std::string input) : cursor(input)
{
    this->input = input;
}

std::string Lexer::getStr(int pos)
{
    if (this->matchStack.size() == 0)
        return this->input;
    while (pos < 0)
        pos += this->matchStack.size();
    while (pos >= this->matchStack.size())
        pos -= this->matchStack.size();

    return this->matchStack[pos];
}

void Lexer::setStr(int pos, std::string str)
{
    if (this->matchStack.size() == 0)
        return;
    while (pos < 0)
        pos += this->matchStack.size();
    while (pos >= this->matchStack.size())
        pos -= this->matchStack.size();

    this->matchStack[pos] = str;
}

Cursor Lexer::getCursorStart(int pos)
{
    if (this->cursorStack.size() == 0)
        return Cursor(this->input);
    while (pos < 0)
        pos += this->cursorStack.size();
    while (pos >= this->cursorStack.size())
        pos -= this->cursorStack.size();

    return this->cursorStack[pos][0];
}

Cursor Lexer::getCursorEnd(int pos)
{
    if (this->cursorStack.size() == 0)
        return Cursor(this->input);
    while (pos < 0)
        pos += this->cursorStack.size();
    while (pos >= this->cursorStack.size())
        pos -= this->cursorStack.size();

    return this->cursorStack[pos][1];
}

bool Lexer::match(std::string str)
{
    this->cursor.skipIgnore();

    const std::string ss = this->input.substr(this->cursor.pos, str.length());

    if (ss == str)
    {
        this->matchStack.push_back(ss); // Getting error if I include this line

        const Cursor startCursor = this->cursor;
        this->cursor.walkTimes(str.length());
        const Cursor endCursor = this->cursor;
        this->cursorStack.push_back({startCursor, endCursor});

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

```cpp
//"test.cpp"
#include "lib/cursor.h"
#include "lib/lexer.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input = "Something to test";

    Lexer lexer = Lexer(input);

    cout << "Start" << endl;
    cout << lexer.match("Something") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling my program with g++ on Windows: `g++ test.cpp lib/cursor.cpp lib/lexer.cpp -o test.exe`

Comment: The problem is some where else. Error, which you are getting is `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()`. This exception is described in documentation - see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_array_new_length . Create minimal   reproducible example and I believe you'll be able to find an issue yourself

Comment: @DmitryMesserman There must be a error in the compiler itself, because even a simple valid snippet like `
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(1);
v.push_back(32);`
Throws the same error

Comment: After trying to compile my project in a gitpod workspace, it works just fine, the version of the gcc used in the gitpod workspace is 9.3.0, while the gcc instaled in my computer is 11.2.0. Is this somewhat related to my issue?

Comment: Yes. There is a good chance that your compiler installation is broken.

Comment: Look at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71757 - I believe it may give a clue, how to workaround this issue

Comment: I was able to run your example successfully in the following environment: `Windows 10, WSL, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, g++-11 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 11.1.0`. Please, let me know if you are interested, and I'll provide instructions how to install this environment. Output, which I got was: `Start` `1`

Comment: @ghsoares How did you solve this?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error when compiling in command line using g++. But it works well in code blocks. To solve this problem try compiling with `-static-libstdc++`. It should solve the problem.

Comment: oh my god thank you! I searched for hours and tried a million things, and this has at last fixed my problem