# Nothing execute when using Vector in C++ with VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vector, g++

## The problem

I have a problem with Vector in C++.
When I try to do basic things with them, my program "doesn't works" anymore.

## What I tried

Searching on Stack Overflow but didn't find something relevant.
But I don't know a lot on this topic so I'm kind of stuck with it.

## Some code:

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
    std::vector< int > arr;
}
```

This program will outputs "Hello world" because I don't interact with the vector.
But if I do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
    std::vector< int > arr;
    arr.push_back(1);

}
```

for example, there is no STDOUT. Hello world is never "printed". And there are no errors.
I'm on Visual Studio code and I compile my program with
`g++ -o progam -Wall main.cpp`
When I run this on the "Terminal" of Visual Studio Code it doesn't works. But when I rut it on another shell it works.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/3czWjzKe8). Are you sure you've saved, you're compiling what you think you're compiling, you're running what you think you're running, etc? Does compiling it from the command line outside of Visual Studio Code make any difference?

Comment: Yes. When doing it on the Visual Studio Code Terminal it doesn't work, but on an external shell it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `g++ -o -Wall main.cpp` will create an executable file called `-Wall`. Unless that's the program you're trying to run, it's not going to work.

Instead you would need something like `g++ -o program -Wall main.cpp` and then run `program`. Both of your examples do the right thing in that case.

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't write it correctly. But when I write it correctly in the VSCode terminal, it doesn't work, but when I run it on another shell it works. I don't know why

Comment: So it was another brick the -Wall.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue (or a very similar one) with VSCode 1.72.2 and g++ 12.1.0.  My fix was to add `"-static-libstdc++"` to the compiler arguments in `tasks.json`.

Some extra breadcrumbs from tracking this down:
Running the compiled program from VSCode terminal or powershell quietly appeared to do nothing.  Executing it from Command Prompt gave a popup dialog: `The procedure entry point _ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv could not be located in the dynamic link library ...`  Googling for that led to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773877/getting-throw-bad-array-new-lengthv-when-trying-to-use-stdvectorpush-back) where [@Thinker-101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13915049/thinker-101) gave the helpful compiler argument.

Answer (score 0):

I create a vector and it tells me that there is an error because it was expected;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 using namespace std;

   int main(){ 

  vector <int> record {12,2,23,23}; //I get a missing ; after record. I don't know why this happens. I'm running it with RunCode on a Macboock Pro M1

   cout<< record[2];
```

}

Comment: Might be a compiler issue try running this code in an online code editor.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34952501)